# Add background image for template file in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, phtml

I want to add background image for `<li>` element in template file. How to add background image in phtml file in magento2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
<li style="background-image:url('<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/demo.jpg'); ?>')">Your text</li>
```